# Hosting Website

Tags: windows, iis, server, nas

I'm hosting a website on Windows Server 2012 R2.  I'm able to access the site with no problem via the assigned ip address and as long as I'm on my home network.  However, when I try to access the site using a public ip address, it defaults to my NAS (MyBookLive).

Baffled.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is intentional.

When a user connects to your ip address, any inbound requests are blocked for security. You would need to open ports on your home router (most likely 80 and 443) and direct the traffic to an internal ip address.

Even if you do this, it is very likely that it would not work. Most residential internet providers do not allow you to host web/mail servers on the internet. If someone compromises your webserver, they would have access to your entire network.

You are better off with a dedicated hosting provider (AWS, Amazon, Google Cloud).